# how to get selected checkbox row data in model dialog box?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, checkbox, modal-dialog

I have problem when i select any checkbox only selected row data should visible inside the model dialog.

1. But i my case when i do click on process(which calls model dialog) where all data coming either i will select or not.
2. But after click on save data button (which is inside the model) data is coming proper what i selected.
3. But I have to show data before click on save data button.

> html code

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>OMR Duplicate Students List</h1>
                <table id="example" class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.selectAll()"
                        /></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in vm.data">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.selected"class="duplicateRow" /></td>
                        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.mobileNumber}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                    <button type ="submit" class="button pull-right"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Process</button>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <pagination page-number='{{vm.pageNumber}}' page-count="{{vm.pageCount}}" total-records="{{vm.totalRecords}}" api-url="duplicate-student"></pagination>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">These Recods You are Selected</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- <div ng-if="data.selected === 'true'"> -->
                <table id="example" class="table">
                    <tr>

                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in vm.data">
                        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.mobileNumber}}</td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
                <!-- </div> -->

           </div>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.process()">Save Data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
```

> Java script code

```
  function StudentDuplicateAccountController($scope, ApiService, $routeParams, $http, $location, $timeout) {
            var vm = this;
            var page = $routeParams.page || 1;
             vm.data = [];


            vm.selectAll =function(){
              angular.forEach(vm.data, function(data){
                if (data.selected) {
                  data.selected = false;
                } else {
                  data.selected=true;
                }
              });
            }


            vm.selectedUsers = [];


            vm.process = function() {
              vm.selectedUsers.splice(0, vm.selectedUsers.length);
              vm.data.forEach(function(studentData){
                if(studentData.selected) {
                    vm.selectedUsers.push(studentData);
                }
              })
                console.log("selectedUsers:::::::::"+JSON.stringify(vm.selectedUsers))
              if (vm.selectedUsers.length === 0) {
                  toastr.info('Selected atleast one record.', null, {
                          timeOut: 3000
                  })
                  return;
              } else {
                ApiService.save()
// some code
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your modal html to

```
   <tr ng-repeat="x in vm.data" ng-if="x.selected">
                        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.mobileNumber}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

to disable process button

create a function like

```
vm.isContainsSelected = function(){
return vm.data.some(function(d){return d.selected})
}
```

then on process button

```
 <button ng-disabled="!vm.isContainsSelected()" >proceess</button>
```

Comment: Thanks its working. and want to know how to restrict process button util atleast one check box selected .

Comment: this is not working when i do select one or more check box, but if i did not select any checkbox then it works. but i need reverse of that.